# How would I go about implementing a schedule system for a bunch of factory stations

Tags: java

I have 5 stations that workers take their tasks from, tasks are of varying length. I am looking to carve up an interactive view that will allow their supervisor to drag around and resize tasks on a day view. Are there any advanced libraries that already do this?

EDIT: Reworded for clarity

Comment: can you use map/reduce for your task?

Comment: I'm not familiar with such a thing.

Comment: read: http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html if it fits, Apache hadoop might help you

Comment: basically map/reduce is a library (originally in c++, but now it exists in almost any language) which modules tasks into two basic oporations: "map" and "reduce". if you can implement map and reduce tasks that will do the job, the library will take care of the rest of the job.

Comment: Ah. I think I explained poorly. I have reworded.

Comment: There's no need for mapreduce here, it's just a database of work + a UI, not actually work to distributed computers. Perhaps something like http://www.jidesoft.com/products/gantt.htm or http://migcalendar.com/ if you're making a desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to go with http://migcalendar.com/ this is the most flexible.